# Get dark style of UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicolor

I have this `UIColor`:

[image]

The **left color** is shown on **light appearance**

The **right color** is shown on **dark appearance**

---

I want to be able to get the **right color** when the device is on **light appearance**,

and be able to get the **left color** when the device is on **dark appearance**.

---

I know I can just duplicate it and create another color, and use that one, but is there a way to get all the variations from a `UIColor` variable from code? thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use UIColor method `func resolvedColor(with traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor` and select the desired trait collection:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    var dark: UIColor  { resolvedColor(with: .init(userInterfaceStyle: .dark))  }
    var light: UIColor { resolvedColor(with: .init(userInterfaceStyle: .light)) }
}
```

---

#### Example

```swift
let systemPurple = UIColor.systemPurple   // r 0,686 g 0,322 b 0,871 a 1,0
systemPurple.dark                         // r 0,749 g 0,353 b 0,949 a 1,0
systemPurple.light                        // r 0,686 g 0,322 b 0,871 a 1,0
```